# Not able to build rpm from src

Tags: centos, erlang, rabbitmq, rpmbuild

I need to rebuild rabbitmq-server-3.1.5 with my changes to some of the static files.
But before doing that I thought of being sure if I can rebuild the rpm without my changes first, and struck with the below issue.
I just installed the source-rpm and edited the SPEC file and changed the version to next minor number, and run the command

```
rpmbuild -ba rabbitmq-server.spec
```

Below is the SPEC file,

```
%define debug_package %{nil}

Name: rabbitmq-server
Version: 3.1.5
Release: 2%{?dist}
License: MPLv1.1 and MIT and ASL 2.0 and BSD
Group: %{group_tag}
#Source: http://www.rabbitmq.com/releases/rabbitmq-server/v%{version}/%{name}-%{version}.tar.gz
Source:rabbitmq-server-3.1.5.tar.gz
Source1: rabbitmq-server.init
Source2: rabbitmq-script-wrapper
Source3: rabbitmq-server.logrotate
Source4: rabbitmq-server.ocf
URL: http://www.rabbitmq.com/
BuildArch: noarch
BuildRequires: erlang >= R12B-3, python-simplejson, xmlto, libxslt
Requires: erlang >= R12B-3, logrotate
BuildRoot: %{_tmppath}/%{name}-%{version}-%{release}-%{_arch}-root
Summary: The RabbitMQ server
Requires(post): chkconfig initscripts
Requires(pre): chkconfig initscripts

%description
RabbitMQ is an implementation of AMQP, the emerging standard for high
performance enterprise messaging. The RabbitMQ server is a robust and
scalable implementation of an AMQP broker.

# We want to install into /usr/lib, even on 64-bit platforms
%define _rabbit_libdir %{_exec_prefix}/lib/rabbitmq
%define _rabbit_erllibdir %{_rabbit_libdir}/lib/rabbitmq_server-%{version}
%define _rabbit_wrapper %{_builddir}/`basename %{S:2}`
%define _rabbit_server_ocf %{_builddir}/`basename %{S:4}`
%define _plugins_state_dir %{_localstatedir}/lib/rabbitmq/plugins


%define _maindir %{buildroot}%{_rabbit_erllibdir}


%prep
%setup -q

%build
cp %{S:2} %{_rabbit_wrapper}
cp %{S:4} %{_rabbit_server_ocf}
make %{?_smp_mflags}

%install
rm -rf %{buildroot}

make install TARGET_DIR=%{_maindir} \
             SBIN_DIR=%{buildroot}%{_rabbit_libdir}/bin \
             MAN_DIR=%{buildroot}%{_mandir}

mkdir -p %{buildroot}%{_localstatedir}/lib/rabbitmq/mnesia
mkdir -p %{buildroot}%{_localstatedir}/log/rabbitmq

#Copy all necessary lib files etc.
install -p -D -m 0755 %{S:1} %{buildroot}%{_initrddir}/rabbitmq-server
install -p -D -m 0755 %{_rabbit_wrapper} %{buildroot}%{_sbindir}/rabbitmqctl
install -p -D -m 0755 %{_rabbit_wrapper} %{buildroot}%{_sbindir}/rabbitmq-server
install -p -D -m 0755 %{_rabbit_wrapper} %{buildroot}%{_sbindir}/rabbitmq-plugins
install -p -D -m 0755 %{_rabbit_server_ocf} %{buildroot}%{_exec_prefix}/lib/ocf/resource.d/rabbitmq/rabbitmq-server

install -p -D -m 0644 %{S:3} %{buildroot}%{_sysconfdir}/logrotate.d/rabbitmq-server

mkdir -p %{buildroot}%{_sysconfdir}/rabbitmq

rm %{_maindir}/LICENSE %{_maindir}/LICENSE-MPL-RabbitMQ %{_maindir}/INSTALL

#Build the list of files
echo '%defattr(-,root,root, -)' >%{_builddir}/%{name}.files
find %{buildroot} -path %{buildroot}%{_sysconfdir} -prune -o '!' -type d -printf "/%%P\n" >>%{_builddir}/%{name}.files

%pre

if [ $1 -gt 1 ]; then
  # Upgrade - stop previous instance of rabbitmq-server init.d script
  /sbin/service rabbitmq-server stop
fi

# create rabbitmq group
if ! getent group rabbitmq >/dev/null; then
        groupadd -r rabbitmq
fi# create rabbitmq user
if ! getent passwd rabbitmq >/dev/null; then
        useradd -r -g rabbitmq -d %{_localstatedir}/lib/rabbitmq rabbitmq \
            -c "RabbitMQ messaging server"
fi

%post
/sbin/chkconfig --add %{name}
if [ -f %{_sysconfdir}/rabbitmq/rabbitmq.conf ] && [ ! -f %{_sysconfdir}/rabbitmq/rabbitmq-env.conf ]; then
    mv %{_sysconfdir}/rabbitmq/rabbitmq.conf %{_sysconfdir}/rabbitmq/rabbitmq-env.conf
fi

%preun
if [ $1 = 0 ]; then
  #Complete uninstall
  /sbin/service rabbitmq-server stop
  /sbin/chkconfig --del rabbitmq-server

  # We do not remove /var/log and /var/lib directories
  # Leave rabbitmq user and group
fi

# Clean out plugin activation state, both on uninstall and upgrade
rm -rf %{_plugins_state_dir}
for ext in rel script boot ; do
    rm -f %{_rabbit_erllibdir}/ebin/rabbit.$ext
done

%files -f ../%{name}.files
%defattr(-,root,root,-)
%attr(0755, rabbitmq, rabbitmq) %dir %{_localstatedir}/lib/rabbitmq
%attr(0755, rabbitmq, rabbitmq) %dir %{_localstatedir}/log/rabbitmq
%dir %{_sysconfdir}/rabbitmq
%{_initrddir}/rabbitmq-server
%config(noreplace) %{_sysconfdir}/logrotate.d/rabbitmq-server
%doc LICENSE*

%clean
rm -rf %{buildroot}
```

I got the below error,

```
escript generate_app ebin/rabbit_app.in ebin/rabbit.app src
erlc -I include -o ebin -Wall -v +debug_info -Duse_specs  -pa ebin src/app_utils.erl
erlc -I include -o ebin -Wall -v +debug_info -Duse_specs  -pa ebin src/gen_server2.erl
erlc -I include -o ebin -Wall -v +debug_info -Duse_specs  -pa ebin src/credit_flow.erl
src/credit_flow.erl:40: Warning: opaque type bump_msg() is not exported
erlc -I include -o ebin -Wall -v +debug_info -Duse_specs  -pa ebin src/delegate_sup.erl
src/gen_server2.erl:526: Warning: erlang:now/0: Deprecated BIF. See the "Time and Time Correction in Erlang" chapter of the ERTS User's Guide for more information.
src/gen_server2.erl:590: Warning: erlang:now/0: Deprecated BIF. See the "Time and Time Correction in Erlang" chapter of the ERTS User's Guide for more information.
src/gen_server2.erl:598: Warning: erlang:now/0: Deprecated BIF. See the "Time and Time Correction in Erlang" chapter of the ERTS User's Guide for more information.
erlc -I include -o ebin -Wall -v +debug_info -Duse_specs  -pa ebin src/dtree.erl
erlc -I include -o ebin -Wall -v +debug_info -Duse_specs  -pa ebin src/file_handle_cache.erl
src/dtree.erl:44: type gb_tree() undefined
make: *** [ebin/dtree.beam] Error 1
make: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
src/file_handle_cache.erl:476: Warning: erlang:now/0: Deprecated BIF. See the "Time and Time Correction in Erlang" chapter of the ERTS User's Guide for more information.
src/file_handle_cache.erl:571: Warning: erlang:now/0: Deprecated BIF. See the "Time and Time Correction in Erlang" chapter of the ERTS User's Guide for more information.
src/file_handle_cache.erl:605: Warning: erlang:now/0: Deprecated BIF. See the "Time and Time Correction in Erlang" chapter of the ERTS User's Guide for more information.
src/file_handle_cache.erl:640: Warning: erlang:now/0: Deprecated BIF. See the "Time and Time Correction in Erlang" chapter of the ERTS User's Guide for more information.
src/file_handle_cache.erl:1139: Warning: erlang:now/0: Deprecated BIF. See the "Time and Time Correction in Erlang" chapter of the ERTS User's Guide for more information.
error: Bad exit status from /var/tmp/rpm-tmp.FjNb8Z (%build)


RPM build errors:
    Bad exit status from /var/tmp/rpm-tmp.FjNb8Z (%build)
[david@thetemplate SPECS]$
```

whereas I didn't face this issue while performing these steps on the other higher version of Rabbitmq-server, and I successfully rebuilt the rpms too. I've no clue why this is happening and also I'm very new to these kind of builds.

would need some expert advice to solve this issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the important line in the error output:

```
src/dtree.erl:44: type gb_tree() undefined
```

In Erlang/OTP 17.0, the type `gb_tree()` was deprecated, and the type `gb_trees:tree()` was introduced to replace it.  `gb_tree()` was finally removed in Erlang/OTP 18.0.

RabbitMQ 3.4.0 changed the type spec to use the newer type, and it is thus the earliest RabbitMQ version that can be built with Erlang/OTP 18.  Here's [the commit where the change was made](https://github.com/rabbitmq/rabbitmq-server/commit/07c80659e7a81b3f03ae2cde508c042735a7b68c).

To solve this problem, either use a newer version of RabbitMQ or an older version of Erlang/OTP.

Comment: I installed an older version of erlang (R14B02) through "yum install", and tried rebuilding the rpm again, but my erlang was not recognized.   It said.......                                                                        [root@thetemplate SPECS]# rpmbuild -ba rabbitmq-server.spec
error: Failed build dependencies:
        erlang >= R12B-3 is needed by rabbitmq-server-3.1.5-2.el6.noarch

Comment: No idea, I'm afraid; I don't know anything about Centos. It sounds like the package name for the older Erlang ends up being different, or something like that...

Comment: Is the Erlang that you reinstalled visible in the system path? E.g. what `which erl` returns? Can you list installed packages to search for Erlang, e.g. `yum list | grep -i erlang`? What happens when you run `erl`? Does it start the Erlang VM an show the Erlang shell?

Comment: Yes, the erl installed was not available in the PATH, I exported the path of erl, its working now!!. But usually the path for erlang should be set automatically, I guess this version requires manual setting.